# Making the div 100% height

Tags: css

I need to make the pink div 100% browser height, `height: 100vh` doesn't work right, there's a scrollbar so it's like 105%...

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #002B5A;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  direction: rtl;
}
#right {} #left {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #CA1F4B;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="right">
  right
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1" id="left">
    left
  </div>
</div>
```

[Check out this Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/dGavhuGt6g)

Comment: Add overflow hidden. Maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `#right`'s height to `100%`.

```
#right {
    height:100%;
}
```

Because `#left` is a child of the `#right` element, it is only being `100%` of the parent's height. As `#right` is only set to `height:auto;` by default, it wont be `100%`.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #002B5A;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  direction: rtl;
}
#right { 
  height:100%;
}
#left {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #CA1F4B;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="right">
  right
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1" id="left">
    left
  </div>
</div>
```

(Look at snippet in full screen)

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/bAhl4hLQ58)

Comment: No worries glad I could help! @odedta

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the min-height and changing the height to vmax, vmin or vh.

```
#left {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #CA1F4B;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/dGavhuGt6g#